# Cannot record from Windows Stereo Mixer in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio, mixer

How to capture desktop audio with Audacity or similar programs?

I need to capture sound which is produced by programs.

I remember I should select windows mixer to record it, but currently I hear nothin with audacity.

Why?

Windows is Windows 8.

Is see in record device window, that no sound goes through Windows Mixer record device

[image]

As you see on picture, Windows Media Player plays sound, while monitor shows no activity.

Why? And how to fix?

**UPDATE**

Sound is visible in tray applet in the following way:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Windows Sound Recorder also records nothing.

Comment: Make sure your playback is going through the same device as stereo mix (i.e. your onboard soundcard). Also, that icon looks more like line-in...

Comment: I hear the playback via my headphones. If this is wrong device, then where is correct one? The name spells "Stereo Mixer" in Russian.

Comment: Are your headphones plugged into a analog port? If not (e.g. USB headset), then that would be a different device. Try the speaker output.

Comment: Yes they plugged into usual analog socket.

Comment: Choose *Stereo mixer* in Audacity, not system-wide.

Comment: I tried both, result is the same.

Comment: Windows has a built in in sound recorder function you can find in accessories I do believe, try that, if it works let us know.

Comment: You might want to try to use [Virtual Audio Cables](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) to route your audio output back into a virtual recording device.

Comment: Also, http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=4826

Comment: Disconnect all physical audio devices since it's obvious from the picture you have speakers and heaphones plugged in at once. Plug in only the speakers in jack on jack on the back of the computer, select the line out as the source, double check to make sure it is working, disconnect the speakers and then plug the headphones in after, not before, after, and test with those as well, if it doesn't work with the headphone jack on the front you will need to use the line out jack on the back.

Comment: Did anything we recommended work yet.

Comment: @user88311 how can it depend on jacks? isn't it internal digital setup? I need not capture analog sound, I need digital sound go to recording software

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how many of these steps have been completed yet, but I will try to cover the essential steps

#### Make sure that you have stereo mix output enabled in Recording Devices

You can right click on in the box to show Disabled and Disconnected devices. To enable a device, right click on it and select `Enable`

[image: Recording Devices]

#### In audacity, ensure that you are recording from the Stereo mix source

[image: Audacity Source]

If you click the record button, Audacity should now record a stereo track of whatever is being output by your computer.

If you have further problems ensure that

1. All other sound devices are unplugged from your computer.
2. Speakers/Headphones are enabled as the default playback device.
3. Your audio drivers are up to date.
4. All other recording devices are disabled